# Could not find file ...\Temp\...\Sitecore.core.dacpac

Tags: sql-database

I am trying to package a local instance of sitecore 9, and keep running into an error after running the script provided by Sitecore.

The error is as follows

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\usernamehere\AppData\Local\Temp\tempDacPacs4cbaf6a5-5242-4ef6-af6f-1ed93c3e5427\Sitecore.core.dacpac'.
```

The script I am running comes from this site:

https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/working_with_sitecore_azure_toolkit/packaging/packaging_a_sitecore_solution_for_the_microsoft_azure_app_service

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the DB users in your `connectionstring.config` have enough privileges to generate a dacpac and/or if you have all the prerequisites installed on your machine:

- SQL DAC Framework x64 & x86
- SQL CLR Types x64 & x86

All the dependencies are listed in the `Prerequisites.json` SIF-file.